# open Adobe Flash IDE, open windows explorer, crash

Tags: flash, windows-vista, crash, adobe-flash-cs3

I installed Adobe Flash CS3 on my Vista Ultimate 32-bit machine (4GB Ram) last year. I occasionally had a problem where if I had opened the Adobe Flash IDE, and then opened Windows Explorer, the machine would freeze and require a reboot. Recently, this problem has gotten much worse to the point where it's very difficult for me to get any work done.

The crash usually does not occur the very first time I open explorer -- it can be anywhere from the first to the faifth time or beyond. Besides explorer, it can also freeze if I open a open/save dialog box, but I assume this is the same issue.

I've tried to diagnose this by looking at the memory dump file, but none is generated. I checked the settings in control-panel/system, and also increased the size of my page file, but still no memory dump. Also, there seems to be no event in the event log. I've reinstalled Flash CS3 also.

I've also googled thoroughly, of course. I have idea where to go from here and any advise on how to solve this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is a programming site, you probably want something like serverfault.com ...

However if it was me, I'd be keeping an eye on things like the memory usage, cpu usage, to see what's going wrong.  If it's memory, then identify if it's Adobe doing it, or something else.

Comment: I was considering serverfault, but I figured users on this site would have more experience with the Flash IDE. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Server Fault. It belongs on Super User.